# Get large number of records in Silverlight using RIA

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services, ria

I am developing web application using `silverlight` 5 and entity framework with wcf ria services to get data from oracle.

My load operation fails when trying to load more than 2000 records. How can we get large number of records in single load operation method call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the  setting in web.config called `maxItemsInObjectGraph` set to int.MaxValue.

```
i.e.
<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Hope this helps.